# ViewPager causes wrong layout display

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

[image]

I have added viewpager in an activity with the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.45">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/imgdetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the toolbar colour has moved and the viewpager has gone to the center of the screen.

Comment: how do you actually want to display your toolbar and viewpager?

Comment: i want the toolbar to be on top of the screen and the viewpager to be exactly below it.

Comment: I figured it out. Placing the viewpager inside a linearlayout made it work properly.

Comment: if you use LinearLayout completely, then your FrameLayout container will be of no use, if you want that to be on full screen. but if you only want that in specified weight inside LinearLayout, then its okay.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way. Just specify the height of the elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/imgdetail"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgdetail">

</FrameLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you need to put the toolbar inside the frame layout. And if so, consider removing the wight for the toolbar and just leave the wrap_content.
2. Change the height of the layouts with weight specified to "0dip".
3. If all else fails consider changing the wights to whole numbers and add them to make the wight_sum of the linear_layout e.g.toolbar frame layout gets 9, view pager gets 3, frame at the bottom gets 8 and weight_sum is 20.

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to implement your layout using `RelativeLayout`. Use `RelativeLayout` and make the `ToolBar layout` the top child and put `ViewPager` below "Toolbar layout".

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/imgdetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</FrameLayout>
```